# My printer won't print black

Tags: printing, troubleshooting, inkjet-printer, multi-function-printer, all-in-one

I have an all-in-one HP OfficeJet 6500 printer/scanner/copier/fax. It uses 4 cartridges (C, Y, M, K). I have only used original HP cartridges. The black (K) cartridge has about 20g of ink left and the printer is reporting that it is nearly full.

Just recently the black part of the print faded as if the ink has run out (it hasn't - 1<sup>st</sup> paragraph) and now if I print a page the black elements are non-existent whereas colour ones are fine - that's whether I print something from a PC or use one of the printer's own status reports.

I'm not sure whether the issue is with that cartridge or did the printing head clog or something. I told printer to clean its heads but that didn't help. What can I do / try?

I have ordered a new black cartridge, should get it next week. If it is the cartridge issue that should help...

Comment: The print head might be clogged and head cleaning might be making it worse. See the newer part of my answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/268489/8672).

Comment: By the way, the new cartridge weighs 71g.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the print head is clogged.  You can use rubbing alcohol on a cotton ball or Q-Tip to clean the head.  If that doesnt fix the problem, I have poured  alcohol in a plastic cup and sat the cartridge in it so the head is submerged.  This should dissolve any clog after a few minutes.

Comment: I got the new cartridge today and it works fine. I'll try your tip, though. Thanks.